# Differences between compare and == for std::string

Tags: c++, string, compare

I am getting different results when using `==` or `std::string::compare` between two strings.

This is the code I am executing.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "W";
    char tmpChar = 'W';
    std::string str2(1, tmpChar);
    
    bool equalCompare = str1.compare(str2);
    bool equalSign = (str1 == str2);
    std::cout << "Compare result: " << equalCompare << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Equal sign result: " << equalSign << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I guess it has to do with how I am creating `str2`, but that is the way I found out to convert a single char to a string.

Comment: I saw that post and I thought that they should be equal. eeroika answer is right. compare return an int and I thought it was a bool. The difference is in the casting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Differences between compare and == for std::string

The difference is in what they return. `==` returns true when the strings compare equal and false otherwise. `compare` returns negative integer when `*this` is before the argument, zero when strings are equal, and positive integer when the argument is before `*this`.